# Open new tab with image data URI

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

First, I have a Canvas which I conovert to dataURL.

After getting DataURL, I send this to a new window.
Then the picture show great but when I try to make right-Click -> Save Picture As... nothing done.

I try with iFrame or with img and I already have the same problem

Thanks

```
    var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

    var win = window.open();
    win.document.write('<iframe src="' + dataURI  + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

Comment: Try to to set the URI in a image src. <img src="Your_URI"> If you need it to be a iframe i have no idea how to make that possible

Comment: Also, don't use `document.write()`. Use `appendChild()` on the `body` instead.

Comment: I try with img problem exactly the same.

then I try to write directly in body and get exactly same behavior...

Answer (score 0):

Try this without an `iframe`. It worked to download `jpeg` files:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = yourDataURL;            

var w = window.open("");
w.document.write(image.outerHTML);
```